# AngularJS templates fail to load over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, https

I got my SSL from Cloudflare and they are directly assigning it to my domain as well as automatically redirecting all `http` to `https`.

With that being said, I'm struggling to get my angular templates to load over https.

The error message is:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mydomain.io/components/index/#/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mydomain.io/components/index/header'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

It seems somewhat straightforward but I've been trying to fix the issue and I can't...

This is how I'm loading my templates from my directive.js file:

```
app.directive('navHeader', function() {
    return {
        templateUrl: function() {
            var useHTTPS = window.location.href.indexOf('https') > -1;
            if (useHTTPS) {
                return 'https://mydomain.io/components/index/header.html';
            } else {
                return 'header.html';
            }
        }
    };
}),
```

but it clearly doesn't work...

Any ideas? Could it be cloudflare's fault?

Comment: Did you try `templateUrl: '/components/index/header.html'`?

Comment: @joelkornbluh yes, same problem, which was why I tried this method... I should add that my header.html and directive.js are in the same folder `index`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be the cause of @Cloudflare,

because of you are trying to access the data of **https** **instead of http**, but the thing is that server is responding to that protocol or not, so you need to **check redirection on server side,**

if any request will come from http or https then it will always redirect to https server.

Comment: How would I fix this issue? I'm not really sure what the problem is to be honest...

Comment: on that server what technoloy code that you have implemented over there,
if nodejs is there then simple create http and https server and make redirection route for that.